# How to get group result using measure in power bi

Tags: powerbi, measure

I want to group the product name and cost per unit using measure. Can anyone help me with this?.

I have table like this - SUMMARIZE(Data,Data[Product name],Data[Cost Per Unit]) - How to calculate sum from this result.

For example I should get result like Chain - 500 by using measure

[image]

Comment: There will be a group option under transform tab in power query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi create a new calculate table and use [ADDCOLUMNS](https://dax.guide/addcolumns/) to do the aggregation

```
ADDCOLUMNS (
    SUMMARIZE ( Data, Data[Product name], Data[Cost Per Unit] ),
    "Sum of cost per unit", SUM ( Data[Cost Per Unit] )
)
```

Note:
This is not recommended please use power query group by as much as possible